# Can the Arduino IDE be used to develop plain old C programs?

Tags: c, arduino

I have a simple Arduino sketch that spans several files. There is a function signature in an h file, and the definition in the C file.

If I attempt to compile ("Verify") the sketch, I get "undefined reference" errors to the function defined in a C file. Changing the file name from *.c to *.cpp resolves the issue, but I don't want to define the file as a C++ file. Is it possible to compile plain old C files in Arduino?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but this was posted on reddit a few days ago: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/10/15/taking-the-training-wheels-off-the-arduino/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Arduino IDE is very limited, my advice: avoid it. You have some alternatives you can find here: http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DevelopmentTools

---

- Develop for Arduino using Minibloq graphical programming environment.
- Arduino CMake build system
- Ino command line toolkit for Arduino
- Develop for Arduino using AVR-Ada
- Develop for Arduino using Eclipse
- Develop for Arduino using Bitlash
- Run Arduino from the command line
- Build using Cmake
- Build using Scons
- Build using build_arduino.py
- Getting a Chumby talking to Arduino
- Running Arduino on the XO laptop (AKA the $100 laptop)
- Arduino in Sharp Netwalker
- Arduino on OpenSolaris
- Using Arduino Libraries in CodeBlocks
- Develop for Arduino using Kdevelop
- Using assembly language source files in the Arduino IDE: Assembly in Arduino